# grpc insecure_channel (python) with .onion address

Tags: python, grpc, tor

From a python gRPC client is it possible to connect to a grpc gRPC using an onion address?

For example attempting to connect to a channel initialised like this:
`grpc.insecure_channel("thisisatestmb4h37vkcb5yuis644766qunwslshw7cz7kamasiehfic.onion")`

Results in

```
...
    grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "DNS resolution failed for service: thisisatestmb4h37vkcb5yuis644766qunwslshw7cz7kamasiehfic.onion"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1630517174.713156000","description":"Resolver transient failure","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":1361,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1630517174.713155000","description":"DNS resolution failed for service: thisisatestmb4h37vkcb5yuis644766qunwslshw7cz7kamasiehfic.onion","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/dns_resolver_ares.cc","file_line":360,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1630517174.713143000","description":"C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=A name=thisisatestmb4h37vkcb5yuis644766qunwslshw7cz7kamasiehfic.onion is_balancer=0: Domain name not found","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":724,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1630517174.713141000","description":"C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=AAAA name=thisisatestmb4h37vkcb5yuis644766qunwslshw7cz7kamasiehfic.onion is_balancer=0: Domain name not found","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":724}]}]}]}"

...

is_balancer=0: Domain name not found
```

Thanks!

Adam

Comment: From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.onion): ".onion ...addresses are not actual DNS names", hence why DNS resolution fails for the address. I don't know much about onion routing, but wouldn't you need a proxy to have your requests passed on?

Comment: @alkasm thanks for writing back, I'm new to grpc but i have a simple grpc server instance running on the port 8080, and I have tor setup to use a hidden service which points at the grpc server. So I was hoping to get the client app to connect with the server via the onion address. I've been able to get to a simple python rest server via an onion address so was hoping i could do the same with grpc

Comment: Although for the Node.JS client rather than Python, I think this issue reflects the issue resolving `.onion` address with gRPC: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/992

Comment: The resolution of that issue was to have Tor expose an `HTTPTunnelPort` and configure gRPC to use it as a proxy server to connect through using the `http_proxy` environment variable. When used that way, gRPC never actually resolves the `.onion` address. Instead, it resolves the address of the proxy and connects to it, and sends it the `.onion` address without processing it at all.